# Only accept first record using INSERT statement inside for loop

Tags: c#, mysql, odbc

I tried this but only first record was inserted and other records are not inserted of 71 records. Error occurred when inserting in second loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= dtRaffleEntries.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
   for (int c = 0; c <= Convert.ToInt32(dtRaffleEntries.Rows[i]["RaffleEntries"].ToString()) - 1; c++)
   {
                        errorline = dtRaffleEntries.Rows[i]["ORNumber"].ToString(); //FLR

                        sbRaffleEntries.Append("INSERT INTO `tblraffleentry` ");
                        sbRaffleEntries.Append("(");
                        sbRaffleEntries.Append("`PromoCode`,`TransactionAmount`,");
                        sbRaffleEntries.Append("`TransactionDate`,`TransactionTime`,");
                        sbRaffleEntries.Append("`CardName`,`CardNumber`,");
                        sbRaffleEntries.Append("`BUCode`,`StationName`,");
                        sbRaffleEntries.Append("`MerchantID`,`TerminalID`,");
                        sbRaffleEntries.Append("`ORNumber`,`Remarks`,");
                        sbRaffleEntries.Append("`CreatedBy`,`DateCreated`,");
                        sbRaffleEntries.Append("`DateUpdated`,`filename`");
                        sbRaffleEntries.Append(")");
                        sbRaffleEntries.Append(" VALUES");
                        sbRaffleEntries.Append("(?,?,CONVERT(?,DATETIME),CONVERT(?,DATETIME),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,CONVERT(?,DATETIME),CONVERT(?,DATETIME),?) ");

                        insertRaffleEntries.Parameters.AddWithValue("PromoCode", RafflePromoCode);
                        insertRaffleEntries.Parameters.AddWithValue("TransactionAmount", dtRaffleEntries.Rows[i]["TransactionAmount"].ToString());
                        insertRaffleEntries.Parameters.AddWithValue("TransactionDate", Convert.ToDateTime(dtRaffleEntries.Rows[i]["TransactionDate"].ToString()).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
                        insertRaffleEntries.Parameters.AddWithValue("TransactionTime", Convert.ToDateTime(dtRaffleEntries.Rows[i]["TransactionTime"].ToString()).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
                        insertRaffleEntries.Parameters.AddWithValue("CardName", dtRaffleEntries.Rows[i]["CardName"].ToString());
                        insertRaffleEntries.Parameters.AddWithValue("CardNumber", dtRaffleEntries.Rows[i]["CardNumber"].ToString());
                        insertRaffleEntries.Parameters.AddWithValue("BUCode", dtRaffleEntries.Rows[i]["BUCode"].ToString());
                        insertRaffleEntries.Parameters.AddWithValue("StationName", dtRaffleEntries.Rows[i]["StationName"].ToString());
                        insertRaffleEntries.Parameters.AddWithValue("MerchantID", dtRaffleEntries.Rows[i]["MerchantID"].ToString());
                        insertRaffleEntries.Parameters.AddWithValue("TerminalID", dtRaffleEntries.Rows[i]["TerminalID"].ToString());
                        insertRaffleEntries.Parameters.AddWithValue("ORNumber", dtRaffleEntries.Rows[i]["ORNumber"].ToString());
                        insertRaffleEntries.Parameters.AddWithValue("Remarks", " ");
                        insertRaffleEntries.Parameters.AddWithValue("CreatedBy", UserName.ToString());
                        insertRaffleEntries.Parameters.AddWithValue("DateCreated", dateTimeNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
                        insertRaffleEntries.Parameters.AddWithValue("DateUpdated", dateTimeNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
                        insertRaffleEntries.Parameters.AddWithValue("filename", filename);

                        insertRaffleEntries.CommandText = sbRaffleEntries.ToString();
                        insertRaffleEntries.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        count++
                         }
                    count2++;
                    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(((int)((double)(i + 1) / dtRaffleEntries.Rows.Count * 100)), CompleteText);
                }
```

The error says its the mysql syntax but icheck it is correct and executing the first loop successfully. getting error in second loop and so on so forth.

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(dtRaffleEntries.Rows[i]["RaffleEntries"].ToString())` Why are you converting to string then back to (I presume) integer?

Answer (score 2):

After the internal *for* add this line

```
....
for (int c = 0; c <= Convert.ToInt32(dtRaffleEntries.Rows[i]["RaffleEntries"].ToString()) - 1; c++)
{
    insertRaffleEntries.Parameters.Clear();
    .....
```

After the first loop you add again the same parameters and the same command text a second time duplicating everything. This result in an exception message talking about too many parameters and invalid syntax. A better and slight more performant approach should be to define your parameters and your text just one time outside the loop and setting just the value inside the loop

For example

```
string cmdText = @"INSERT INTO `tblraffleentry` 
`PromoCode`,`TransactionAmount`,`TransactionDate`,`TransactionTime`,
`CardName`,`CardNumber`,`BUCode`,`StationName`,`MerchantID`,`TerminalID`,
`ORNumber`,`Remarks`,`CreatedBy`,`DateCreated`,`DateUpdated`,`filename`)
 VALUES
 (?,?,CONVERT(?,DATETIME),CONVERT(?,DATETIME),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,
 CONVERT(?,DATETIME),CONVERT(?,DATETIME),?)";
insertRaffleEntries.CommandText = cmdText;
insertRaffleEntries.Parameters.Add("PromoCode", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
// Define the other parameters with the proper DBType here 
.....

for (int i = 0; i <= dtRaffleEntries.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
   for (int c = 0; c <= Convert.ToInt32(dtRaffleEntries.Rows[i]["RaffleEntries"].ToString()) - 1; c++)
   {
        errorline = dtRaffleEntries.Rows[i]["ORNumber"].ToString(); //FLR
        insertRaffleEntries["PromoCode"].Value =  RafflePromoCode;
        // Set the value for the other parameter here 
        .....
        insertRaffleEntries.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
}
```

Comment: I see you've expanded your answer since I last looked. This is better than mine, I'll delete.

Comment: Yes, but I have overlooked at the stringbuilder problem that you correctly have highlighted in yours.